How to download all listed companies on Yahoo Finance with detailed data (e.g., sector, market cap) for research purposes?
I'm currently working on a data science research project and I need to download a comprehensive dataset of all listed companies available on Yahoo Finance. The dataset should include detailed information such as:

Company name
Sector
Industry
Market capitalization
Other relevant financial data

I am looking for guidance on how to accomplish this. Specifically:

Is there an existing API or tool that allows for the extraction of this data from Yahoo Finance?
If not, what would be the best approach to scrape this data efficiently?
Are there any limitations or legal considerations I should be aware of when extracting data from Yahoo Finance?

I need data of all exchange listed companies.
Any advice, suggestions, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
